# как остановить атоматическое переключение табов при клике по одному из табов

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function() {
        var t = 1;
            function switchTabs() {
                if (t > 3) t = 1;
                if (t == 1) $('a.my-tab[href="#tabs-1"]').click();
                if (t == 2) $('a.my-tab[href="#tabs-2"]').click();
                if (t == 3) $('a.my-tab[href="#tabs-3"]').click();
                t++;
            }
        var sw_tabs_timer1 = window.setInterval(switchTabs, 3000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">  
  <ul class="tabNavigation">
    <li><a class="my-tab" href="#tabs-1">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="my-tab" href="#tabs-2">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="my-tab" href="#tabs-3">3</a></li>
  </ul>  
  <div id="tabs-1">
    img
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    img
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    img
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Учитывая что вы в вашем коде используете .click() то отловить нормальный клик будет затруднительно) Мне кажется выбран не совсем верный подход к задаче. Дополните ответ задачей которую нужно решить. Кажется, что табы должны переключаться сами, а по клику их нужно остановить

Comment: Задача состоит в следующем, необходимо, что бы табы автоматически переключались, а по клику необходимо остановить автоматическое переключение, что бы пользователь выполнял это действие самостоятельно

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Что значит "атоматическое"? Что происходит сейчас? Что демонстрирует этот пример?

Comment: А после того как юзер клацнул и ушел дальше табы должны начат ьснова сами по себе переключаться или до перезагрузки страницы потом?

Comment: Сейчас табы переключаются самостоятельно меня изображения, без вмешательства пользователя, как слайдер. Необходимо что бы по клику самостоятельное переключение остановилось

Comment: да, должны опять сами начать двигаться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.originalEvent` - https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

`Event.isTrusted` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

```js
$(function() {
  var t = 1;

  function switchTabs() {
    if (t > 3) t = 1;
    console.log("switchTabs - ", t);
    if (t == 1) $('a.my-tab[href="#tabs-1"]').click();
    if (t == 2) $('a.my-tab[href="#tabs-2"]').click();
    if (t == 3) $('a.my-tab[href="#tabs-3"]').click();
    t++;
  }
  var sw_tabs_timer1 = window.setInterval(switchTabs, 1000);

  $('a.my-tab').click(function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.isTrusted && sw_tabs_timer1) {
      sw_tabs_timer1 = clearInterval(sw_tabs_timer1);
      console.log("stopped switchTabs");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tabNavigation">
    <li><a class="my-tab" href="#tabs-1">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="my-tab" href="#tabs-2">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="my-tab" href="#tabs-3">3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    img
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    img
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    img
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: табы перестали самостоятельно переключаться

Comment: @ИгорьЛебедев Еще бы. Пожалуйста.

Comment: так при загрузке страниы не переключаются, без клика по ним

Comment: теперь отлично! Спасибо

Comment: @ИгорьЛебедев Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.